# Cannot boot windows after deleting linux partition

Tags: linux, grub2, grub

I had Windows 10 pre-installed on the computer. Then after creating a 30GB partition I installed Linux Mint 18.1 and dual-booting worked smoothly.I wanted to try out other Linux distributions, starting with Ubuntu. So I (naively) thought that if I deleted the 30GB partition and extended the Windows partition for the now unallocated 30GB, the computer would boot to Windows 10, since this is the only installed operating system. But instead it boots to:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.7
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
grub>
```

I have tried to resolve this in several ways but nothing works. The solution that I repeatedly read about is to find the Linux partition and install that operating system once again with USB (in my case that is Linux Mint 18.1). I am stuck at step one, because I can't find the right partition. This is what I get:

```
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0, gpt4) (hd0, gpt3) (hd0, gpt2) (hd0, gpt1)

grub> ls (hd0)/
error: unknown filesystem. //// the same for (hd0, gpt4), (hd0, gpt3), (hd0, gpt2)

grub> ls (hd0, gpt1)/
efi/
```

According to the article I read I should see something like this at one of the partitions (but I do not):

```
grub> ls (hd0, 1)/
lost+found/ bin/ boot/ cdrom/ dev/ etc/ home/  lib/
lib64/ media/ mnt/ opt/ proc/ root/ run/ sbin/ 
srv/ sys/ tmp/ usr/ var/ vmlinuz vmlinuz.old 
initrd.img initrd.img.old
```

How can I fix this?
(I have a USB with the operating system I deleted, Linux Mint 18.1)

Comment: Did you try booting to a live version of MINT and run a boot-repair from there, yet?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to boot from an Windows 10 USB and run System Repair. If that doesn't work, try to boot from an Ubuntu USB(if you have access to another pc to make an bootable USB) and install, you will be prompted with a menu where you can create and edit partitions. Make a new partition for Linux. And then install. After that you should be able to use GRUB again. You can also try the same with Mint. To boot from USB, press f8(or f2 or f12 -depending on your system) after you press the ON button and see the logo of your laptop/pc. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Install Linux Mint or Ubuntu on the 30GB partition. It will detect the "other" OS and make a new Grub menu with an option for booting Windows.

Comment: The 30GB partition does not exist anymore, I merged it with Windows partition before the computer rebooted to grub so I cannot do that.